# Google Maps API V3 - Custom Tiles

Tags: google-maps-api-3, imagemap, tile, maptiler

I am currently working on Google Maps API V3 over [here](http://apps.humannetworklabs.com/GoogleMapAPI.html)

If you zoom between 21 to 23, there will be an image overlay on the map. The image takes too long to load and I have decided to break it into different tiles for easier loading. I am using Automatic Tile Cutter to cut the image into tiles.

I have problems with the script;

```
    var OrgX = 31551;   // the Google Maps X value of the tile at the top left corner of your Photoshop document 
    var OrgY = 50899;   // the Google Maps Y value of the tile at the top left corner of your Photoshop document
```

**First question** How do you find the values of X and Y from the photoshop document?

Let say if I manage to solve the first question.

**Second question** Is the below code correct to display the tiles depending on the zoom level? Or am I missing any codes?

```
var BuildingsLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return "http://search.missouristate.edu/map/tilesets/baselayer/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
});

map.overlayMapTypes.push(BuildingsLayer);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using Automatic Tile Cutter, I used and recommended MapTiler. 
Not only it slices the image into tiles and it also generates out a javascript tiles script to use it.

However, the script is written in v2. You can edit the codes according:

*v3 tiles script*

```
var maptiler = new google.maps.ImageMapType({ 
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) { 
return zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + (Math.pow(2,zoom)-coord.y-1) + ".png"; 
}, 
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256), 
  isPng: true 
}); 

var map; 

function initialize() { 
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas")); 
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(36.07, -112.19)); 
 map.setZoom(11); 
 map.setMapTypeId('satellite'); 
 map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, maptiler); 
}
```

[Credits](http://groups.google.com/group/maptiler/browse_thread/thread/ff1fcb260028edbf/8ccb743f86d567c0?lnk=gst&q=v2+to+v3#8ccb743f86d567c0)

Comment: The latest version of MapTiler available from: http://www.maptiler.com/ supports the Google Maps V3 automatically. There is no need for changes in the JavaScript code anymore.

Comment: maptiler adds in every image 'maptiler', very annoying, and ruins the image for me. Recommend you download the command line tool GDAL instead.