# Customizing a user-created google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm wondering if it is possible to insert a map (with some lines) that was created on google.com into a javascript that uses the v3 api. I tried to read it up/google it, but I couldn't find anything so I'm guessing it isn't possible?

If yes, - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a map created in "My Places" on [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com), those can be accessed as KML which can be displayed on a Google Maps API v3 map using [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer)

[Map created in "My Places"](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=215141252881397372270.0004ce6eeb9cf1a94e100&msa=0)

[Same KML displayed on a Google Maps API v3 map with KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkto.html?filename=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fauthuser%3D0%26vps%3D2%26hl%3Den%26ie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D215141252881397372270.0004ce6eeb9cf1a94e100)

To answer your additional question in the comments, the simplest way to do it is to take the [example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) and replace the URL with yours.  So yes, you can just change the filename URL in the first line of the initialize function to the URL of your KML:

```
function initialize() {
  filename = 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml';
```

Comment: Exactly that. I'll look into that and hope I can get it running. Thanks!

Comment: Did that by mistake and changed it before reading your reply. Cheers & sorry.

Comment: Can you help me a little more? I understand how to overwrite the code by changing the second url that you posted so it links to my KmlLayer, but I don't understand how I integrate my Kml Google Link inside that example script. Can I not just change the cta.kml to my URL? Do I need to set all the other parameters?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Yes, you can just change that or replace "filename" in the constructor for KmlLayer.

Answer (score 0):

I think ImageMapType is good for you.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ImageMapType

Comment: Similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596597/google-maps-api-v3-custom-tiles